# Edit og:title and description on Squarespace for Facebook

Tags: facebook, squarespace

I've edited and added to advanced page injection code on my Squarespace site, but Facebook is still picking up a meta tag "article" with a title I've never seen before. What else can I do to reset the og:title that Facebook is identifying with my website?

Comment: What is the URL of the page you have problem with? Have you tried https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.